# Rails convert delete_if to sql statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written an exception using delete_if and I am running into issues and would like to use an SQL statement or something using active record.

Here is my delete_if statement:

```
Format.all.delete_if { |f| ( f.location_ids.sort & User.current.location_ids.sort ) == User.current.location_ids.sort }
```

Basically, the statement is If all user location_ids are included in format location_ids then delete.

Comment: To confirm, you're asking how to translate that Active Record statement in to a plain 'ol SQL query? If so, I'm confused then, because [`delete_if`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/delete_if) is an array function; it won't affect anything on the database level.

Comment: Since you want to know the SQL to do the deletes you should include the relevant table structures in the question.

Comment: The delete_if is removing the items from the query. What I need is a query that only selects what I need rather than select all then delete from array. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NathanBiles I don't think we have enough information yet to help you build such a query. If you can describe the table structures (for `Format` and `User` I guess?), and describe in plain english what the query should pull up (or filter out), that would be helpful. By the looks of the statement you have now, it seems like you want to pull up all `formats` that don't have the same list of `location_ids` as the current user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but maybe this code is what you're looking for:

```
current_user_location_ids = User.current.location_ids.sort

formats_to_destroy = Format.all.to_a.select do |format|
  format.location_ids.sort == current_user_location_ids
end

formats_to_destroy.map(&:destroy)
```

**ATTENTION:** It will actually destroy the record(s) in the DB!